# Forward and inverse indexing of a triangular adjacency matrix stored in a single vector

Tags: arrays, graph

I have a map with points, I would like to know the distance between each point. (This is possibly known as Undirected Cyclic Graph). As there are a lot of points, with my storage being limited, the array needs to be dense. For 4 cities (n = 4), I need 6 indexes to map these 4 cities:

```
Index #, City1 <> City2 
=========================
Index #0, 1 <> 2
Index #1, 1 <> 3
Index #2, 1 <> 4
Index #3, 2 <> 3 
Index #4, 2 <> 4
Index #5, 3 <> 4

Index total = 6
Cities = 4
```

Or viewed triangularly:

```
(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)
(2-3)(2-4)
(3-4)
```

This (either direction/edge -- all roads are two-way). If I have 260 cities, I need 33670 indexes instead of 260x260 or 67600 indexes. Ex: With 4 cities, Index #4 is the distance from 2 to 4 (or 'flipped' as 4 to 2).
Note: The above is an example with 1 to each other city, then 2 to each city except 1, ... , the 2nd-to-last city to last city (n-1 to n). Other 'shapes' are open for discussion (such as reverse order or even another scheme).

If I have 260 cities, how can I tell what cities zero-based index #i refers to? are there 2 formulas I can use to get city1 and city2 from the index and back again? (Ex: Index #33333 is 234 to/from 249).

```
getIndex(city1, city2) // returns index
getCities(Index)       // returns city1, city2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to derive these with some high school algebra. But computing them is pretty expensive.

Let `(i,j)` be the edge from city `i >= 1` to city `j > i` and let `p >= 0` be the corresponding index in the vector representing the linearized triangular matrix. Then

```
p = j * (j - 3) / 2 + i
```

With this formula, the linear layout is:

```
(i,j) = (1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(1,4)(2,4)(3,4)...
  p   =   0    1    2    3    4    5 ...
```

E.g. for `(1,2)` we have `2 * (2 - 3) / 2 + 1 == 0` as you'd expect. And for `(2,4)` it's `4 * (4 - 3) / 2 + 2 == 4`.

To go the other way,

```
j = floor((3 + sqrt(8 * p + 1)) / 2)
i = p - j * (j - 3) / 2
```

For `p == 0`, `j = floor((3 + sqrt(1)) / 2) == 2`.  Then `i = 0 - 2 * (2 - 3) / 2 == 1`.  For `p == 4`, it's `j = floor((3 + sqrt(33)) / 2) = 4`, then `i = 4 - 4 * (4 - 3) / 2 = 2`.

The square root is probably why you don't often see this technique used. Note integer square root will work fine, which can be faster than floating point in some circumstances.

All in all, it's probably faster, simpler, and almost as storage efficient to use an array of pointers to rows of increasing length.

**Addition**

It turns out after all that there *is* a way to eliminate the square root.  We cut the triangular array in half and fit the pieces to make a rectangle. For a graph with `n = 5` vertices:

```
j                             p = 0   1   2   3   4
=  ---                           -------------------
2 | a |                         | a $ j | i | h | g |                           
   -------                       ----===------------
3 | b | c |        is arranged: | b | c $ f | e | d |
   -----------                   -------------------
4 | d | e | f |                   5   6   7   8   9
   ---------------
5 | g | h | i | j |
   ---------------
i = 1   2   3   4
```

where the right hand side is a vector written in two rows.

Now for odd n,

```
    { n*j + i - k,                     if j < n/2 + 2
    {    where k = 2*n+1
p = {
    { kk - (n*j + i)                   otherwise
    {    where kk = (floor(n/2)+4)*n
```

The constants `k` and `kk` can be computed one time when the array is created.

To go the other way, let `j' = floor(p/n)`  and  `i' = p mod n`.  Then

```
i = i' + 1,  j = j' + 2                 if j' <= i'
i = n - i',  j = n - j'                 othewise
```

I will let you work out the even `n` case.

These are only a bit more expensive than normal 2d array indexing, due to the 2-way branch in each case.

Comment: This is a good response. You're correct with reversing's expense. I wonder if there is some other way organize the array to decode/encode a faster with another 'shape'.  (The city indices can start at 0 or 1.)

Comment: @codeaperature Not without unused space. Regardless of how you arrange the indexing, the forward transform is always quadratic (based on the sum 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2), so the inverse always needs a square root. Of course you could use binary search with the forward transform to avoid the inverse completely, but a fast hardware square root could easily be faster than that.

Comment: @codeaperature Actually your question gave me another idea.  See above.

Comment: @codeaperature I re-titled the article so that it will be more easily searchable for others with the same question.