# From an Upper Triangle Matrix to a Flat Vector: What's the relationship of index?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Dear experienced friends, I am trying to figure out what's the relation of the index when I convert an **Upper Triangle Matrix** to a **Flat Vector**. Suppose we have a matrix `a` likes following:

```
    a11  a12  a13  a14
    a21  a22  a23  a24
    a31  a32  a33  a34
    a41  a42  a43  a44
```

It's easy to convert it to a flat `vector/list` through `list(a[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0])])`. And the result would be `[a11,  a12,  a13, a14, a22, a23, a24, a33, a34, a44]`.

***I am trying to figure out: Is there a simple method that we can map the matrix's index to the vector's index?***

For example, the `a11` is the `1st element` in vector, and `a23` is the `6th element`. Is there a function/method that we can map the matrix index of `11` to `1` in the vector, and map `23` to `6` in the vector? (Especially when the shape of the square matrix goes from `4` to `N`?)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) are a good place to start. The length of the result array is a triangular number, and the number of elements on the **rows below** the element is a triangular number. For example, with N=4 the result array length is 10 (1+2+3+4). The number of elements on the rows below `a23` is 3 (1+2) since there are two rows below `a23`. So the only thing left is the number of element after `a23` on row 2. There's one, so the answer is 10-3-1 = 6.

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, I just need to check the element on the diagonal. Then the number of elements below/above is a Triangular Numbers. Finally, I just need to compare the column index of this diagonal element and the target one. Very clear and easy way!Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forward and inverse indexing of a triangular adjacency matrix stored in a single vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669884/forward-and-inverse-indexing-of-a-triangular-adjacency-matrix-stored-in-a-single)

Comment: Thank you for the link, Davis. Yes, my question is quite similar to this one: They are all easy-derive but computing-expensive. I think what @user3386109 mentioned perfectly solve this problem. Thanks again!